# Ordering comma separated column values from related tables in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL server. I would like to have a query for below mentioned requirement. I am at Beginner level in SQL
I have two tables as shown below:

**Table: Car**

| Id | CarName | Company | LaunchYear |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Audi Q7 | Audi | 2022 |
| 2 | Ford GT | Ford | 2021 |

**Table: CarType**

| TypeId | CarId | Colour | PetrolRate | DieselRate | ElectricRate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | PLATINUM | 10000 | 9000 | 11000 |
| 2 | 1 | GOLD | 9500 | 8500 | 10500 |
| 3 | 1 | SILVER | 9250 | 8250 | 10250 |

I require the output in a single row for unique car.

It must have comma separated values of rates based on their colours.

The value of colours must be ordered by alphabetically ascending and the rates must be aligned with the colours.

I tried below query but I am getting multiple rows for a single car:

```
select * 
from Car c
left join CarType ct on ct.CarId= c.Id
where c.Id = 1
```

**Please refer below required output:**

**Output**

| CarId | CarName | Company | LaunchYear | Colours | PetrolRates | DieselRates | ElectricRates |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Audi Q7 | Audi | 2022 | GOLD,PLATINUM,SILVER | 9500,10000,9250 | 8500,9000,8250 | 10500,11000,10250 |

**Answer Acceptance Reason:**

I have accepted the solution which uses XML PATH because I am having SQL Server 2016.

Note: String_AGG() is for SQL Server 2017 and higher versions. The solution listed with it is also appropriate. *(Only one solution can be accepted as an answer :))*

Comment: Please include your attempt in the question. Have you take a look at `string_agg()` ?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am using SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is achievable using `FOR XML PATH` string function since sql server 2005

```
select t1.id, t1.CarName, t1.Company, t1.LaunchYear, t2.Colours, t2.PetrolRates, t2.DieselRates, t2.ElectricRates
from Car t1
inner join
    (select  CarId
       ,stuff((SELECT ', ' + cast(Colour AS varchar(50)) [text()]
         from CarType 
         where CarId = t.CarId
         for xml path(''), type)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') Colours
        ,stuff((SELECT ', ' + cast(PetrolRate AS varchar(50)) [text()]
         from CarType 
         where CarId = t.CarId
         for xml path(''), type)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') PetrolRates
        ,stuff((SELECT ', ' + cast(DieselRate AS varchar(50)) [text()]
         from CarType 
         where CarId = t.CarId
         for xml path(''), type)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') DieselRates
        ,stuff((SELECT ', ' + cast(ElectricRate AS varchar(50)) [text()]
         from CarType 
         where CarId = t.CarId
         for xml path(''), type)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') ElectricRates
    from CarType t
    group by CarId) as t2 on t2.CarId = t1.id
```

Comment: Please don't say it it the `stuff()` that does the job. It only removes the first comma. The worker in this case is `for xml path`.

Comment: @Kendle, please try again

Comment: @Kendle, yup i found the error, i just edited my answer

Comment: @Kendle, this is just an option if using <SQL server 2016

Answer (score 1):

We can use `STRING_AGG( ~ , ',')` to make a comma seperated list with `WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY TypeId)` to be sure that the different values are in the right order.

```
create table cars (id int, carName varchar(25), Company varchar(25), LaunchYear int)
insert into cars values (1,'Audo Q7','Audi',2022),(2,'Ford GT','Ford',2021);
create table carType(TypeId int,CarId   int,Colour  varchar(10),PetrolRate  int,DieselRate  int,ElectricRate int);
insert into carType values
(1, 1,  'PLATINUM',10000,9000,  11000),
(2, 1,  'GOLD'    ,9500 ,8500,  10500),
(3, 1,  'SILVER'  ,9250 ,8250,  10250);

select
  c.id,
  c.carName,
  c.Company,
  c.LaunchYear,
  string_agg( Colour ,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY TypeId) Colour,
  string_agg( PetrolRate,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY TypeId) PetrolRate,
  string_agg( DieselRate,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY TypeId) DieselRate,
  string_agg( ElectricRate,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY TypeId) ElectricRate
from cars c
left join carType t
on c.id = t.carID
group by
  c.id,
  c.carName,
  c.Company,
  c.LaunchYear
GO
```

```
 id | carName | Company | LaunchYear | Colour               | PetrolRate      | DieselRate     | ElectricRate     
 -: | :------ | :------ | ---------: | :------------------- | :-------------- | :------------- | :----------------
  1 | Audo Q7 | Audi    |       2022 | PLATINUM,GOLD,SILVER | 10000,9500,9250 | 9000,8500,8250 | 11000,10500,10250
  2 | Ford GT | Ford    |       2021 | null                 | null            | null           | null
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=29a91de16907c7abbeb96098615dee94)*

Comment: Thank you @Kendle. I appreciate your efforts. In my case I have SQL Server 2016. But I insist you to keep this solution for the once using SQL Server 2017 and ahead.